# What OTP pattern to use for gen_server socket broadcast?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

So I have a non- blocking OTP socket server very similar to the one in Learn Yorself Some Erlang:

http://learnyousomeerlang.com/buckets-of-sockets

The supervisor passes the listening socket to dynamically spawned gen_servers, each of which can accept a single connection; in this way the listening socket isn't blocked by (blocking) calls to gen_tcp:accept, and each gen_server spawned by the supervisor effectively represents a single client.

Now this is all very nice and I can talk to the server via telnet, a simple echo handler echoing my requests.

But what if I want to extend this into a simple chat server ? Obvious thing missing here is the ability to send a broadcast message to all connected clients. But currently none of the gen_server clients know about the existence of any of the others!

What's a sensible OTP- compliant pattern for one gen_server to be able to get pids for all the others ? Only way I can think of is to have some kind of mnesia/ets table containing pids/usernames as part of the gen_server state variable, but somehow this doesn't seem very OTP- like.

Thoughts ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an ETS table to store the Pids would be the way to go. I would use a supervised process as the table manager and set up monitors on Pids that are added to the ETS table, that way you can detect when a process dies and can remove it from the ETS table.

For fault tolerance when working with ETS you need to take some precautions, see [Don't Loose your ets Tables](http://steve.vinoski.net/blog/2011/03/23/dont-lose-your-ets-tables/) for a good intro on how to do this.

But for a real system I would use either the [pg2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/pg2.html) or [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc) modules doing this kind of stuff. pg2 is included in OTP and geared more towards distributed systems, gproc is more flexible. Both use ETS tables to store the data.